# Can conversations be clicked through?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Conversations in Skyward Sword can take... a while. The text is slow to appear, and it seems you have to wait for *all* of it to appear. It literally makes me grind my teeth in rage when I accidently talk to the same character a second time, and have to wait through four or five text boxes for 30 seconds or more.

Is there any way to hurry my interlocutors up, and keep my dentist happy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can hold <kbd>A</kbd> down and the conversation text will appear faster. Other than that, no.

Comment: It should be noted that "faster" here doesn't really mean much. In fact in most cases you have to try really hard to even notice the difference, it's so pathetically miniscule (25% faster at best, I'd say).

Comment: Yeah, it has been noted that the penalty for falling off the city of skyloft (before you can fly yourself) is having to talk to the knights.

Comment: Is is interesting that Zelda never fixed this issue. So annoying.

Comment: But the story is so enthralling!